# jQuery is returning undefined string from function in .each()

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, return, each

I'm trying to return a string from of function called 'tjekdet', but it won't return anything but undefined. I just need it to return the string, so I can append the result to $(this).

The reason for me to do it this way, is because the request for test2.php takes around 40 seconds, so I'd rather do them one by one instead. But nevermind that.

Does this have something to do with synchronous calls? Or am I just completely missing something really basic?

```
    function tjekdet(name) {
    $.get("test2.php", { test: name },
        function(data){
        // alert(data); returns correctly in the alert
        return data;
       });
    }

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.button').live("click",function() {
            $(".navn-list").each(function() {
                var navn = $(this).text();
                var tester = tjekdet(navn);
                alert(tester); // returns undefined
            });
        });
```

Comment: The result of tjekdet will not be the result of invoking `$.get` since, as you hinted in your question, `$.get` is exectued asynchronously.

Comment: This question comes up daily, yet I can never find one when I need it to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this have something to do with synchronous calls?

Yes. Well, really it has to do with *asynchronous* calls. Your `tjekdet` function will return `undefined` before your AJAX `get` returns anything.

Put the alert inside the success callback:

```
$.get("test2.php", { test: name }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    //Do whatever you need to do here, not in the other function
});
```

You could use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `jQuery.get` and set the `async` option to `false`, but that's rarely a good idea and tends to lock up the browser completely until the data has returned.

Comment: Great, thank you. BUT! The alert returns 'yes', 'no', 'yes' etc as it should for each. But now I want to add that string to the specific div, but I can't use `$(this).append(data);` for some reason?

Comment: I would suggest passing the `div` into the `tjekdet` function. You can then refer to it by using that argument. For example, `function tjekdet(elem) { ... }`. You can then get the name of the element inside the function, rather than passing it in, and you have a reference to the `div` to update it later.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) If you have any more problems, just ask a new question on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

`get` is shorthand for `ajax` with a certain set of options.  AJAX is asynchronous.  This means that the request has not yet returned when your function completes.

The only option to return something like that from a `get` is to make it a synchronous call, which is a **bad idea** in almost every case, as the browser will hang while waiting for a response.

You should instead do whatever it is you need to do with the result of the request in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

Because `tjekdet()` doesn't actually return anything. The return statement in `tjekdet` really belongs to the anonymous callback, and has nothing to do with the return of `tjekdet`.

Additionally, the callback inside `tjekdet` is invoked asynchronously, so it will probably not even have executed yet when you call `alert(tester);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look like:

```
function tjekdet(name, callback) {
    $.get("test2.php", { test: name },
        function(data){
            callback(data);
    });
}

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.button').live("click",function() {
        $(".navn-list").each(function() {
            var navn = $(this).text();
            tjekdet(navn, function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

inside `tjekdet` your ajax call is async, and you can execute some action when that call is completed...but since tjekdet will return right away, you cannot expect to get correct value from tjekdet, but you should call some callback method instead.